# Azure custom domain not validating against azure zone record

Tags: azure-dns

In the portal I added dns zone records for mydomain.com

- A record for the web app ip address and
- TXT record for the web app name with value mysite.azurewebsites.net

I set the name servers to

```
ns1-04.azure-dns.com
ns2-04.azure-dns.net
ns3-04.azure-dns.org
ns4-04.azure-dns.info
```

as mentioned in the Azure portal DNS Zones blade

However when I try to add the custom domain to my app service, and I try to validate it
Selecting A record for the hostname record type

I get an error on Domain ownership

> To verify domain ownership create TXT and A records with your DNS
>   provider using the configuration below
>   [image: error message]

[Update]

I decided to try buying a domain from the Buy Domain option inside the custom domain blade.

The app service worked with this newly bought domain within minutes.

I noticed that this created a www CName record not a TXT record for mysite.azurewebsites.net

Also the name servers mentioned in the Azure DNS Zone were of the format

```
ns1-07.azure-dns.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the CName record is also required, even though the Domain ownership message in the screen shot does not mention it.